# Converting SQL formula to Power BI DAX formula - having trouble

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am trying to write this SQL statement in Power BI and having problems getting this to work.

```
SELECT Distinct
       [Entity_ID]
       ,Count([Dealer_Code])

FROM [dw].[dealerDim]

Where 
       Year([Dealer_setup_date]) = YEAR(GetDate())
       and [Dealer_inactive_flag] = '0'

Group By
       [Entity_ID]
```

I have a table that has the Dealer_setup_date and the inactive codes per Dealer - I cannot figure out the formula to bring in the fields to include in the formula.